# Horário de brasília no Angular incorreta após mudança no horário de verão

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

Eu tenho uma aplicação em Angular e preciso exibir a hora correta no sistema, não houve mudança de horário de verão no Brasil e estou informando a hora no sistema com atraso de uma hora.

**app.module.ts:**

```
// Locale
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import pt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
registerLocaleData(pt);

providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'pt-BR' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' },
]
```

**component.ts:**

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
moment.locale('pt-br');

interval(1000).subscribe(() => this.horaAtual = moment().toDate());
```

Após a mudança de horário de verão, não consigo mais obter a hora correta pois esta com uma hora de atraso.

**Como consigo obter a hora correta de Brasília?**

Comment: Mas já fazem quase uma semana e o servidor de onde pega o horário não arrumou ainda??

Comment: A unica opção é pegar a hora do computador, mas eu tenho um sistema de agendamento e isso afetou também o horário da agenda, já que eu uso o horário local.

Comment: No sistema está com uma hora de atraso e não sei como corrigir isso.

Comment: Não conheço muito do moment, mas, se fizer moment().hour() +1 não resolve?

Comment: sim se fizer moment().add('hour', 1) resolve a visualização da hora, mas a minha agenda vai continuar com horário local atrasado.